# How to set the margins for a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating an on-screen figure that has two subplots: one is an image and the other is a graph. The margins are extremely large around the figures.

How do I adjust the margins around the figures?

---

Most questions that I searched for involved saving images (bbox seemed perfect), and using axes instead of subplots for absolute positioning.

Here is the code I used to generate the figure:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    ...

    self.figure, (self.picture, self.intensity) = \
        plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(12, 5))
    self.figure.set_dpi(80)
    #self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)
    #self.picture.imshow(np.random.uniform()) #size=(5, 50)))
    self.intensity.plot(np.random.random()) #size=641))

    self.intensity.autoscale(axis='x', tight=True)
```

Comment: Lots of functions work only for Pylab mode and saving figures. I want something that works for a `Figure` object.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have a look at [`plt.tight_layout()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout) or [`plt.subplots_adjust()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust) or `fig.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')`.

With `subplots_adjust` you can adjust most parameters, while `tight_layout()` and `bbox_inches='tight'` are more or less semi automatic.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use plt.set(), with the attributes given in the adjust plot menu, e.g. set(top=0.82) etc.

Comment: I have not found matplotlib.pyplot.set in the documentation http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html

Comment: They have probably changed their API in the last 2 years.