# matplotlib.pyplot: remove white space and keep same size while saving the image

Tags: python, image

I know some some people have asked this problem before, but the solutions they provided seems do not work to mine.
I just give the links below and maybe they are helpful for you.

[Matplotlib plots: removing axis, legends and white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces)

[How to set the margins for a matplotlib figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898919/how-to-set-the-margins-for-a-matplotlib-figure)

As described in the problem title, I use following code to handle this problem.

```
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('seg_missi5.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

And I want the saved image with no white spaces and the same size with the original one.

I have tried using `print img.shape` to see the size of `img`, it shows `(342, 548, 3)`, which is the same as the original one, but the saved image, it don't. It's size if `438 x 675`, which is bigger and has white spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably, matplotlib might not be the best tool to achieve this (although it's certainly possible). I propose the [Python Image Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) as a substitute. Using this library, you can save your image like this:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img))
im.save('outfile.png', "PNG")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `pad_inches=0`

```
plt.savefig('seg_missi5.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Default size is 0.1. You can get more information from  http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig